# First steps for migrating a Facebook Canvas App (untouched since Mar 2010) to OAuth and HTTPs --

Tags: facebook, canvas, https, oauth

I am not a professional programmer. I am "a kitchen table programming enthusiast." My question is at the very end of this narrative.

In March of 2010, I figured out how to introduce my interactive database driven web app to the world by turning my web app into a Facebook Canvas Application.

Basically I built my web app prior to March 2010 using MYSQL, PHP, HTML, JavaScript, etc. using "dummies" books. Once I was convinced that my web app was functional as a standalone website, I pored through Facebook online documents to figure out how to turn my app into a FB Canvas App.

That was in March of 2010. Back then the process for turning a web app into a FB Canvas App basically involved getting files like the following, and saving them to the directories on my web host server:

```
-- At public_html:
    -- config.php
    -- facebook_desktop.php
    -- facebook_mobile.php
    -- facebookapi_php5_restlib.php
    -- fbtest.htm
    -- JSON.php
    -- jsonwrapper_inner.php
    -- xd_receiver.htm
-- At public_html/php:
    -- facebook.php
```

Now here is my question:

My app has been working fine since March 2010, but now (since this morning) my app doesn't work at all (doesn't even open). I suspect this is due to requirements that changed related to migration to OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS --  requirements which I need to learn how to respond to.

What should be my first step toward at least enabling myself to continue using my own app on FB? Once we have figured that out, I will be seeking guidance on how to once again enable other FB members to use my app.

I hope some will find this thread helpful.

Thank You,
FL

Answer (score 0):

There's an overview here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/ which links to the docs and the blog posts which gave examples of how to migrate

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, so much!

I have begun reviewing the material you have referred. I will continue to dig in, but I'd like to let you know that for now, I see these phrases which raise questions in my mind:

```
-- "If you are only using the PHP SDK (Software Development Kit) for authentication..."
-- "If you are using the JavaScript SDK for login..."
-- "Update to PHP SDK..."
-- "Update to JavaScript SDK..."
-- "Implementing the OAuth 2.0 authentication system..."
-- "Using the latest SDKs..."
```

Based on details in my original post is one able to determine whether I have currently implemented a PHP SDK or the JavaScript SDK? I don't know that I ever even used an SDK for establishing my means for Authentication and Authorization. I only knew my method as applying for a FB App ID, App Secret and copying a set of files to my server. Was my implementation method from March 2010 so old that it is neither PHP SDK nor JavaScript SDK?

Doesn't "updating an SDK" require that I had first implemented some sort of SDK?

If it turns out that I haven't used an SDK as part of my archaic means for authentication and authorization then what set of instructions is really applicable for me to migrate to OAuth2.0?

I am concerned that without seeing a step by step set of instructions, I will end up with extraneous and conflicting files on my server.

Does anyone know of any migration instructions like, "replace these files (file A, file B, file C and file D) from your web host server with these files (file E, file F, file G and file H)"

Thank you,
FL.

Comment: My current understanding is that in March 2010 I implemented the PHP SDK that was available at that time. Is my understanding correct? Now my task is to implement the latest PHP SDK. What will the process be like? Is the first step to delete all of the nine files mentioned in my initial post above? or Do I keep some of the nine files untouched but replace only some of them? The online documentation has a lot of good detail but not the big picture I need. Please advise.